# Animating multiple instances of a single armature within a single animation

Tags: animation

Looking for some animation advise!

How would one go about animating 2 or more instances of the same object/armature?

ie "Armature_A" and "Armature_A.001", in "Action_A".

Moving "Bone_01" applies to both, but I would need them to act independently.

Is there a way to add a namespace separation?

Is there any way other than to give each bone in "Armature_A.001" a unique name from their "Armature_A" counterpart? That wouldn't be such an issue with only 2, but if I wanted to animate 20, or 200, it's suddenly an insanely gruelling task.

Comment: could you please explain, for example with a drawing?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could do that. The *easiest* way to do this is by actually duplicating your model and armature attached to it. So you will have **ArmatureA** (using **ModelA**) and **ArmatureB** (using **ModelA**).

They both need to physically exist in your scene. I usually tend to place them right behind the cameras, so every group/instance/reference/dupli object/particle or animation track that will reference them will not get them rendered accidentally.

So now you go to the [NLA](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/nla/index.html), Select **ArmatureA** and do animation in the graph editor. On the NLA save the animation clip.

Now, when you want to apply that animation to **ArmatureB**,  it will accept it only after you freeze the clip (it's like making a new fake user material or a new + material). Once you have created (frozen) your NLA track, on the property name of the stored track, select your **ArmatureB**. Now it should move.